# Why not render vue router items in production?

Tags: vue.js

Production build looses something.
I have Vue 3.2.33 project; vite: 2.9.5

When running dev-server all the template renders fine:

App.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div id="menu">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <router-link class="navbar__link" to="/">{{ state.reg }}</router-link>
      <router-link class="navbar__link" to="/Information">{{
        state.info
      }}</router-link>      
      <router-link class="navbar__link" to="/Subscribers">{{
        state.subs
      }}</router-link>
    </nav>
    <LocaleSwitcher />
  </div>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

router config file

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import Information from "@/views/Information.vue";
import Search from "@/views/Search.vue";
import Subscribers from "@/views/Subscribers.vue";
import { useStore } from '@/stores/store'

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Search",
    component: Search,
  },
  {
    path: "/information",
    name: "Information",
    component: Information,
  },
  {
    path: "/subscribers",
    name: "Subscribers",
    component: Subscribers,
  },
  
];
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
});
router.beforeEach((to) => {
  const store = useStore()
  if (!store.hasGroup && to.path !== '/') {
      return '/'
  }
})
export default router;
```

vite.config.ts

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "url";
import vueI18n from "@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import path from "path";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vueI18n({
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/locales/**"),
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  }
});
```

but if I run build for production and run preview server, none of router components(router-link and router-view) render. Reading vite and vue-router documentation does not clarify anything yet. I would be grateful for any help, given that I am often just inattentive

Comment: "but if I run build for production and run preview server" - how? Web server needs to be properly configured to run SPA

Comment: @EstusFlask  actually the problem occurred when I was trying to publish my app on Netlify. Now I'm able to reproduce it by building my app and then running: "npm run preview", which starts: "vite preview --port 5050". It takes "dist" folder as a source, as I got it.

Comment: I see. It's `/Information` in one place, and `/information` in another. Urls are case sensitive, unless they are handled in a special way.

Comment: @EstusFlask, thanks for your suggestion, I've already fixed it. But my problem isn't there.